# R - selecting non-empty cells in each row and create new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have been searching a lot to find a solution but could not. I would appreciate any help. I have a dataframe like below:

```
A B C D

x na na z

x t na na 

na z na x 

y na s  na
```

and my desired output is:

```
A1 B1 

x z

x t  

z x 

y s
```

Comment: By empty do you mean the string "na" or `NA`?

Comment: What is the desired output if a row does not contain two `"na"`, i.e. a different  number of non-`NA` compared to other rows?

Comment: The actual data set is long. I just mocked up the example. The data is very sparse and  I want to only get the non-empty (which is not na/NA) cells.

Comment: Your example assumes that you will always have 2 non-NAs in each row. Is this correct? There is no way that , say, row 1 would be `x   na   na   na`, thus leaving you with only 1 value?

Comment: yes, it will always have 2 values (in this example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your "na"s are actually `NA`s and you would have equal number of `NA`s in each row you want to remove, you could do

```
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])))

#  X1 X2
#1  x  z
#2  x  t
#3  z  x
#4  y  s
```

If you have string "na" then

```
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[x != "na"])))
```

should work.

Comment: I did. Thanks. Just in case, if there are unequal number of NA's and I want a fixed number of columns, lets say 2 in this example. And I have to replace the NA with a 0 or average of rest of the cells. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an operator to make it as readable as possible?

```
library(dplyr)
`%|%` <- function(x,y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x)

df %>%
  transmute(A1 = A %|% B %|% C %|% D,
            B1 = D %|% C %|% B %|% A)
```

Comment: `replace` is in such cases oftentimes (always?) a good / efficient alternative to `ifelse`

Comment: I cannot see how to apply `replace` here. Could you provide a code, please?

Comment: `replace(x, is.na(x), y)`

Comment: I cannot agree. It is not vectorized properly, i.e. it replaces first encountered `NA` with the first element of `y`, and not the respective one.

Comment: You are right! It does not work here as I expected. Note the question mark in my first comment ;) +1

Comment: Thanks for the input!